# Search videos on YouTube inside android application

Tags: android, search, youtube, youtube-api

I want to search for YouTube videos inside my Android App.

(Not with intent to YouTube app!)

All examples/tutorials I found are not for android, Or this api:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=theRelevantSearchKey

Is it the way to do that on Android, get the result by XML from above link and parse it?

There is no official Android tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although there is another API method that uses JSON instead of XML:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=myQuery&key=API_KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_DEV_CONSOLE

Answer (score 0):

[YouTube Direct Lite for Android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) is the best source to see the samples.

And for search, you can plug this one into Android, since it's java. https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java

Comment: The sample shows: "implementation for an Android OS application that captures video, uploads it to YouTube, and submits the video to a YouTube Direct Lite instance." But not Search for keyword as I needed. And for the Search Java class, conceptually you right. It's Java. But in fact this class using lots of non Android code concepts, so it's more easy to implement it yourself rather than convert it to Android java.